# How does Google's 'showing results for' work?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, algorithms, google, search-engine

If I search 'I love to eate my food' on Google then Google will 'show results for' I love to eat my food.... How does this algorithm work?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, no one knows how google search works except what google officially publishes. But I give you a simple algorithm for query correction (I have implemented this previously in production).

It is a simple prediction based on spell-check. First you detect the (possible) typo. Then you find the query which maximizes the likelihood. This search is done in the huge database of user queries plus some language models.